# libspotify API: search result and artist portrait

Tags: spotify

As per API document, sp_artist object is loaded if I search an artist and search complete callback is called. Since sp_artist object is loaded, I assume the artist's portrait URI can be retrieved without waiting for any other call backs. But the result is, sometimes the portrait URI can be retrieved, sometimes it can't. Why? I'm using libspotify version 12 and used **sp_link_create_from_artist_portrait(artist, SP_IMAGE_SIZE_LARGE)** to get the portrait link.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this the same artist that sometimes does and sometimes doesn't work? Otherwise, a lot of artists don't have portrait images. In this case, you can use one of their album's covers in its place.

Comment: Sorry, my bad... I made a typo in my code. It works fine as expected.